# Love2d isDown equivalent for touch control?

Tags: lua, love2d

I have this code for mouse:

```
if love.mouse.isDown(1) then
   self.player:fire()
end
```

So this fires the gun as long as the mouse button is held down. I have onscreen buttons for touch which I can capture individual touches with `love.touchpressed` but this fires the gun one at a time.

I want it so that the player can touch the onscreen button and as long as it is held down the gun fires continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```lua
if next(love.touch.getTouches()) ~= nil then
    self.player:fire()
end
```

or define function `is_empty` or `any`:

```lua
function is_empty(t)
    return next(t) == nil
end

if not is_empty(love.touch.getTouches()) then
    self.player:fire()
end

function any(t)
    return next(t) ~= nil
end

if any(love.touch.getTouches()) then
    self.player:fire()
end
```